# Error in hill.climbing : INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'NULL'

Tags: r, integer, hill-climbing, bnlearn

I'm trying to use hill-climbing function `hc()` in bnlearn package .
Despite that all columns of my data frame are factor and carry no NA values, I still kept getting such error message:

```
Error in hill.climbing(x = x, start = start, whitelist = whitelist, blacklist = blacklist,  : 
  INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'NULL'
```

The following is my hc function code.

```
 hcdata<-hc(data, score = "bic" )
 hcdatafit <- bn.fit(hcdata, train)
```

What might cause this problem? Thanks!

Comment: can you add the results of `str(yourdata)` to the question please (where `yourdata` is the dataframe that you passed to `hc`)